# How to deal with modifying large pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a largish pandas dataframe (1.5gig .csv on disk).  I can load it into memory and query it.  I want to create a new column that is combined value of two other columns, and I tried this:

```
def combined(row):
    row['combined'] = row['col1'].join(str(row['col2']))
return row

df = df.apply(combined, axis=1)
```

This results in my python process being killed, presumably because of memory issues.

A more iterative solution to the problem seems to be:

```
df['combined'] = ''
col_pos = list(df.columns).index('combined')
crs_pos = list(df.columns).index('col1')
sub_pos = list(df.columns).index('col2')

for row_pos in range(0, len(df) - 1):
    df.iloc[row_pos, col_pos] = df.iloc[row_pos, sub_pos].join(str(df.iloc[row_pos, crs_pos]))
```

This of course seems very unpandas.  And is very slow.

Ideally I would like something like `apply_chunk()` which is the same as apply but only works on a piece of the dataframe.  I thought `dask` might be an option for this, but `dask` dataframes seemed to have other issues when I used them.  This has to be a common problem though, is there a design pattern I should be using for adding columns to large pandas dataframes?

Comment: first of all, `dask` doesn't help in your case, because your problem is I/O and memory bound instead of CPU bound, and `dask` is based on `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Dask can use threading, multiprocessing, or distributed computing.  In his case though he needs none of these, merely a way to intelligently handle streaming data from disk.

Comment: whats about using the apply method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using list comprehension + [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['ab'] * 200,
    'b': ['ffff'] * 200
})


import itertools

[a.join(b) for (a, b) in itertools.izip(df.a, df.b)]
```

It might be "unpandas", but pandas doesn't seem to have a `.str` method that helps you here, and it isn't "unpythonic".

To create another column, just use:

```
df['c'] = [a.join(b) for (a, b) in itertools.izip(df.a, df.b)]
```

Incidentally, you can also get your chunking using:

```
[a.join(b) for (a, b) in itertools.izip(df.a[10: 20], df.b[10: 20])]
```

If you'd like to play with parallelization. I would first try the above version, as list comprehension and itertools are often surprisingly fast, and parallelization would require an overhead that would need to be outweighed.

Comment: Wow.  This is incredibly mind numbingly fast.  Using python3 I ended up with: 

`df['course_combined'] = [str(a).join(b) for (a, b) in itertools.zip_longest(df['col1'], df['col2'])]`

Pandas must be doing something very inefficient with iloc, I would have thought that would have been a fast but ugly way to iterate over the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to create a new column in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) or [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)  is with the [`.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   x  y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  a
3  4  b

In [4]: df.assign(z=df.x * df.y)
Out[4]: 
   x  y     z
0  1  a     a
1  2  b    bb
2  3  a   aaa
3  4  b  bbbb
```

However, if your operation is highly custom (as it appears to be) and if Python iterators are fast enough (as they seem to be) then you might just want to stick with that.  Anytime you find yourself using `apply` or `iloc` in a loop it's likely that Pandas is operating much slower than is optimal.